# Warning: Missing argument 1 for getConnection()

Tags: php

```
function getConnection($con) 
     {
        $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','test') or die(mysqli_connect_error());
         // Check connection
         if (mysqli_connect_errno())
           {
             echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
           }
           $query = "ID FROM Student";
           $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

     }
```

Is the error caused due to $con used in the function ? Any help please.

Comment: How do you call this function? Also, what the query is `ID FROM Student`?

Comment: Remove $con from your getConnection()

Comment: I am trying to get a an api response by calling this function to get connection if( strcasecmp($_GET['method'],'ABC') == 0){
      
  $response['code'] = 1;
     $response['status'] = $api_response_code[ $response['code'] ]['HTTP Response'];
     $getconnection = getConnection();
 // $success = settype($getconnection, 'string');
  $success = settype($getconnection, 'string');
  $response['data'] =  $success;
}

Answer (score 0):

It means you're omitting to pass an argument to the function when invoking it, i.e.

```
getConnection(); //<-- no arg passed
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you use `$kon` as parameter and override it then?

But i would define $con to be null if no parameter is passed and if you need it.

like

```
function getConnection($con = null){[..]}
```

If possible I would remove the parameter.

Comment: I am trying to get a an api response by calling this function to get connection to my database if( strcasecmp($_GET['method'],'ABC') == 0){ $response['code'] = 1; $response['status'] = $api_response_code[ $response['code'] ]['HTTP Response']; $getconnection = getConnection(); // $success = settype($getconnection, 'string'); $success = settype($getconnection, 'string'); $response['data'] = $success; }

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create the db-connection ($con) inside your function, remove the parameter from the function declaration:

```
function getConnection() {
 ...
```